# Use Azure keyvault secrets offline when developing .NET core Azure functions

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

When I develop for Azure I usually start copying in some keyvault client code so only keyvault urls will be in my settings file, no secrets can ever end up my git repositories.

After starting to make Azure functions I realized that it was not possible to do this for the trigger connection string for e.g. service bus or blob storage.

The recommended approach seems to connect the app to keyvault directly in Azure when deployed, and just manage secrets locally in Secret Manager, like suggested in 
[this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=windows)

I am not developing alone, so while I am not adverse to using a tool like Secret Manager, I need to still have my offline secrets connected to the Azure keyvault! If others change anything.

**Question:** How do I manage secrets offline in a way that is synchronized with Azure keyvault?

Comment: why do you need to manage secrets offline ? if this is a dot net core app then you can use user-secrets for development purposes locally.

Comment: As I mentioned, that is not considered a reasonable solution where I work. We want the secrets centrally managed in KeyVault. We are okay with a tool like user-secrets, but the content of those settings must be synchronized/connected to keyvault.

Comment: Why is it not possible to have the trigger connection string in the keyvault?

Comment: @DennisdeLaat I would love to know that too..

Comment: @JoeyCai I know how to manage it online. I do not understand how your answer is applicable to my question

Comment: Because you say `I realized that it was not possible to do this for the trigger connection string for e.g. service bus or blob storage.`. I just point out that you could achieve it with `@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=Secret URI with version)`.

Comment: But the context for what you quote is offline! I apologize if that is somehow not obvious

Answer (score 0):

> it was not possible to do this for the trigger connection string for e.g. service bus or blob storage.

In short, it's possible.

Here are steps you could follow and refer to the detailed [article](https://medium.com/@sibeeshvenu/secure-serverless-azure-functions-appsetting-using-key-vault-37869f52c924).

1.Add a System Assigned Managed `Identity` to the Azure Function.

2.Go to the `Access Control` section of your `Key Vault` and click on `Add a role assignment` blade.

3.Go to your `Key Vault` and click on `Access Policies` and then click on Add service principal with secret `GET` permission.

4.When you use ServiceBusTrigger, you set ServiceBusConnectionString in Function ->`Configuration` ->`Application settings`.

```
public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger(_topicName, _subscriptionName, Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] string mySbMsg, ILogger log)
{ ....
}
```

5.Now you change the value of `ServiceBusConnectionString` to the Azure Key Vault reference with `@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=Secret URI with version)`. Then you could run your function successfully with Key Vault.

[image]